# How can I run a Delegate Synchronously?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, asynchronous

I have a method which uses a delegate to update a master page for a SharePoint site.  I won't go into the details of WHY I need this, but I need to ensure the method runs synchronously in-it-entirety before moving-on to the next step in the process.

How can I do this?

**THE CODE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomerPortalBasicSiteProvider : AbstractProvider<bool>, IExecutable
{
    public CustomerPortalBasicSiteProvider()
    {
    }

    List<IProviderSetting> Settings { get; set; }

    public bool Execute(ExecuteParams parameters)
    {
        SetMasterPage(parameters);
        return true;
    }

    private void SetMasterPage(ExecuteParams parameters)
    {
        // NOTE: I need the contents of this method to run synchronously
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
           delegate
           {
               using (var elevatedSite = new SPSite(parameters.SiteUrl))
               {
                   using (var elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
                   {
                       elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                       elevatedWeb.CustomMasterUrl = Settings.Find(x => x.Key == "SPWeb.CustomMasterUrl").Value;
                       elevatedWeb.Update();
                       elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                   }
               }
           });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: THE SHAREPOINT OBJECT LOOKS LIKE:**

```
public static class SPSecurity
{
    public static AuthenticationMode AuthenticationMode { get; }
    public static bool CatchAccessDeniedException { get; set; }
    public static bool WebConfigAllowsAnonymous { get; }

    public static void RunWithElevatedPrivileges(SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated secureCode);
    [Obsolete("Use SetApplicationCredentialKey method instead.")]
    public static void SetApplicationCendentialKey(SecureString password);
    public static void SetApplicationCredentialKey(SecureString password);

    public delegate void CodeToRunElevated();

    public class SuppressAccessDeniedRedirectInScope : IDisposable
    {
        public SuppressAccessDeniedRedirectInScope();

        public void Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the delegate you pass to `RunWithElevatedPrivileges()` is executed asynchronously?

Comment: I am being told it is...and am taking the persons word for it.  Are they wrong?

Comment: I think so, but don't take my (or that person's) word for it: Test it by adding some kind of trace after the call to `RunWithElevatedPrivileges()` and checking that the master URL is indeed always updated before that trace runs.

Comment: I don't know what you meant by synchronous. but code inside the delegate can be run through single thread only.(may be calling thread, or a threadpool thread or whatsoever). Now you can check that with this aspect.

Comment: Whether it is invoked synchronously or asynchronously is up to the code that *invokes the delegate* - i.e. the implementation of `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`; can we see that?

Comment: Thank you for the help: That is all I have to go on...

Comment: @Marc, that method is part of the SharePoint API, the questioner would have to disassemble that code. (I'm pretty sure it runs synchronously but I did not use it *that* much, so I cannot be definitive about that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, RunWithElevatedPrivileges runs the delegate synchronously. The delegate is only required to run the code in another security context.
Just to be sure, you could write log messages at the end of your delegate code and as first code after the call to RunWithElevatedPrivileges. 
If the later is first in the log file, RunWithElevatedPrivileges runs asynchronously.